# Alignment for range slider breaks when customizing with plain CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to customize a slider for a small project I'm working on. I've placed it next to a default slider in the following snippet:

```css
input[type=range].custom {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 150px;
   height: 10px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   background: blue;
}

input[type=range].custom::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: rgb(41, 62, 72);
   border: 3px solid white;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(41, 62, 72);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Skills:</p>

    <div>
        <span>C++</span>
        <input type="range" name="volume" class="custom"/>
        <input type="range" name="volume" />
    </div>
</body>
```

I can already see one issue, namely that the vertical alignment has been tampered with:

[image]

This is no good, as I would like to adjust the slider placement using the `vertical-alignment` CSS property for inline elements.

Why does the alignment break when I customize the slider? How can I prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Align child items vertically centered in a `div`

##### **TL;DR.** Use `display: flex;` and `align-items: center`

Historically centering anything vertically within a block-level container used to be pretty tricky, but with the modern CSS layout methods like `flexbox` or `grid` it became fairly trivial.

In the edited code snippet below, I only added the `flex` styling to the parent `div`. Hope this should give you something to start with.

```css
input[type=range].custom {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: blue;
}

input[type=range].custom::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(41, 62, 72);
  border: 3px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(41, 62, 72);
}

.skill-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Skills:</p>

  <div class="skill-block">
    <span>C++</span>
    <input type="range" name="volume" class="custom" />
    <input type="range" name="volume" />
  </div>
</body>
```